# Subset dataframes in a list based on a single value of a corresponding vector

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to conditionally subset data.frames in  a list of data.frames based on value in a vector. Basically, whenever `a > 0` I would like to subset the corresponding list element to have that many randomly-sampled rows.

```
# a list
l <- list( data.frame(x=1:5, y = 1:5),
           data.frame(x= 11:15, y = 11:15),
           data.frame(x=21:25, y = 21:25) )

# a vector
a <- c(3, 1,-2) 

# one possible permutation of the desired output
[[1]]
  x y
1 1 1
2 3 3
3 5 5

[[2]]
   x  y
1 13 13

[[3]]
   x  y
1 21 21
2 22 22
3 23 23
4 24 24
5 25 25
```

I have been trying to do this with `purrr::map_if()` as follows, but
my function only uses the first value of `a` as the number of rows for all of the data.frames. That is, the first and second elements of the list are subset to 3 rows, but I'd like the second element to have just 1 row.

```
f <- function(x, count) {x[sample(nrow(x), count),]}

purrr::map_if(l, a > 0, f, count = a)
```

Is there a way to pass the value in 'a' for each iteration of `map_if()`?
Or some other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R one with `Map` + `ifelse`

```
> Map(function(x, k) x[sample(nrow(x), ifelse(k > 0, k, nrow(x))), ], l, a)
[[1]]
  x y
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5

[[2]]
   x  y
2 12 12

[[3]]
   x  y
2 22 22
1 21 21
5 25 25
3 23 23
4 24 24
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following solution. Here you actually need to use `purrr::map2` or `base::mapply` or `base::Map` since you are should iterate over 2 vectors or lists in parallel.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map2(a, l, ~ if(.x > 0) {
  .y %>% 
    slice_sample(n = .x)
} else {
  .y
})

[[1]]
  x y
1 2 2
2 4 4
3 3 3

[[2]]
   x  y
1 11 11

[[3]]
   x  y
1 21 21
2 22 22
3 23 23
4 24 24
5 25 25
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
# a list
l <- list( data.frame(x=1:5, y = 1:5),
           data.frame(x= 11:15, y = 11:15),
           data.frame(x=21:25, y = 21:25) )

# a vector
a <- c(3, 1, -2) 

map2(
  .x = l,
  .y = a,
  .f = ~sample_n(tbl = .x, size = ifelse(.y > nrow(.x) | .y < 0, nrow(.x), .y))
    )
#> [[1]]
#>   x y
#> 1 4 4
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 1 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    x  y
#> 1 13 13
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>    x  y
#> 1 24 24
#> 2 21 21
#> 3 23 23
#> 4 22 22
#> 5 25 25
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>